# --mandir command not found

Tags: xbox-360, configure, ushare

I am trying to set up uShare for my xbox, but I run into the next error.
I have installed uShare and the source code, and also extracted the source code with

```
wget http://ushare.geexbox.org/releases/ushare-1.1a.tar.bz2 -O - | tar -jxvf -
```

and I set the directory to this ./ushare-1.1a. Next I have to configure some things using the following code:

```
./configure --prefix=/ --bindir=/usr/bin --mandir=/usr/share/man
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Unknown option "--mandir=/usr/share/man".
See ./configure --help for available options.
```

When I open the help option as said above, I can't seem to find any option which is called --mandir

What does this command mean and what does it do?

(I am relatively new to Ubuntu so I have no clue what this means. I am following a how-to from ubuntu for what I am trying to do (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xbox360Media))

Comment: Any reasons why you could not install uShare from the repositorties? See https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ushare

Comment: @Takkat I have uShare installed already, I just need to configure it now. This is where I run into problems

Comment: Installing an application the usual way will not let you run into these issues, just saying... ;)

Comment: @Takkat I have tried installing it the usual way before, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `README` included in source, you should run following commands to configure and compile the source:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
```